# Сервлет: дважды отрабатывает контроллер - где искать?

Tags: java, servlet

Добрый день!
Есть проблема: при запуске приложения контроллер сервлета отрабатывает два раза - это видно по логам и при отладке. Подозреваю, что проблема в маппинге. Вот фрагмент моего web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Может кто подскажет где искать решение проблемы?

Comment: С этим фрагментом web.xml все в порядке.

Comment: Это видимо не весь web.xml. Где определение ContextLoaderListener? Или вы используете аннотации для конфигурирования контекста приложения? Обычно такая ситуация возникает, если неправильно разнесены бины по контекстам приложения и web (точнее бины присуствуют в двух контекстах одновременно).

Comment: смотреть нужно конфигурацию, описанную в dispatcher-servlet.xml, а так же сам контроллер